# Both constant and 0 polynomials have infinitely many roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose that $P(x)=P(x+c)$ where $P$ is a polynomial with real coefficients and $c$ is a constant. It is obvious that if $r$ is a root,then $r+c$ is also root and hence the chain continues to show that there are infinitely many roots.This polynomial is not necessarily $0$ rather a constant polynomial.Again we know that $0$ polynomial is the only one with infinitely many roots.Doesnt this show a contradiction?

Comment: Since $P(x)$ has finite degree, it can only have finitely many roots. So you cannot "continue the chain" with $r+c$ over and over to find infinitely many roots. In this case, you don't even have any roots to begin with, since $P(x)$ is constant nonzero.

Comment: No, as you suppose that you have a root, which is not the case for the constant polynomials that are not $0$.

Answer (score 1):

No. If $P(x)$ is constant but not the null polynomial, then it has no roots. So, althouth it's indeed true that if $r$ is a root then $r+nc$ is also a root if $n\in\Bbb N$, it does *not* follow from this that $P(x)$ has infinitely many roots.